# Yii - CJuiAutoComplete no results displaying even though network request has status 200

Tags: php, yii, autocomplete, widget, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to implement the CJuiAutoComplete widget and can't get any results to display. here's my code:

`HighSchoolsController.php`

```
public function actionSearchHighSchools() {

$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$model = new HighSchools;
$criteria->compare('SchoolName',$model->SchoolName,true);
$criteria->compare('City',$model->City,true);
$criteria->compare('State',$model->State,true);

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider($model, array('criteria'=>$criteria));
$highSchools = $dataProvider->getData();
$return_arr = array();
foreach($highSchools as $highSchool){
  $return_arr[] = array(
    'value' => $highSchool->SchoolName,
    'label' => $highSchool->SchoolName,
    'id' => $highSchool->id,

  );
}
return CJSON::encode($return_arr);
```

}

`_buildEducation.php (view file)`

```
<?php
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'name'=>'highschool',
    'sourceUrl'=>$this->createUrl('highSchools/searchHighSchools'),
    'options'=>array(
      'minLength'=>'2',
    )
  ));
?>
```

now, in my controller function if i var dump the `CJSON::encode($return_arr)` instead of returning it i get the following output:

```
string(688) "[{"value":"ALBERT P BREWER HIGH SCH","label":"ALBERT P BREWER HIGH SCH","id":"1"},{"value":"ALBERTVILLE HIGH SCH","label":"ALBERTVILLE HIGH SCH","id":"2"},{"value":"ALICEVILLE HIGH SCH","label":"ALICEVILLE HIGH SCH","id":"3"},{"value":"ALMA BRYANT HIGH SCH","label":"ALMA BRYANT HIGH SCH","id":"4"},{"value":"ANDALUSIA HIGH SCH","label":"ANDALUSIA HIGH SCH","id":"5"},{"value":"ANNISTON HIGH SCH","label":"ANNISTON HIGH SCH","id":"6"},{"value":"ARAB HIGH SCH","label":"ARAB HIGH SCH","id":"7"},{"value":"ASHVILLE HIGH SCH","label":"ASHVILLE HIGH SCH","id":"8"},{"value":"ATHENS HIGH SCH","label":"ATHENS HIGH SCH","id":"9"},{"value":"AUBURN HIGH SCH","label":"AUBURN HIGH SCH","id":"10"}]"
```

so i know the widget is being sent the right data, and like i stated in the title the network request comes back ok with a status of 200 but for some reason the results will not display. can anyone see something that i'm doing wrong? I pulled the code from the Yii docs and forums and tailored to my needs but the the code is essentially the same as people who said it works for them

Answer (score 0):

figured it out... needed to echo the json results instead of return them